# NDSolve with parametric endpoint

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, parametric-functions, boundary-conditions

I want to solve numerically a system of ODEs of the form:

$$\ddot{y}+3\frac{\dot{b}}{b}\dot{y}=2Cy(y^2-1)$$
and
$$\dot{b}^{2}=1-b^{2}+\frac{D}{2\sqrt{C}}b^{2}\left(\dot{y}^{2}-C(y^{2}-1)^{2}\right)$$
for the independent variables $y(t)$ and $b(t)$ and with the free parameters $C$ and $D$. The boundary conditions are:
$$y(0)=0~,~~\dot{b}(0)=0~,~~b(\zeta)=0~,~~\dot{y}(\zeta)=0$$
where $\zeta$ is an unknown variable that should depend on $C$ and $D$. If $\zeta$ was well specified (e.g. $\zeta=1$) then I suspect that the system can be solved with "ParametricNDSolve" command for the parameters $C$ and $D$. However, I can't find a way to include the boundary condition with $\zeta$ unspecified. In particular, I would like to plot something like $\zeta$ vs $C$ for $D=const$.

Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question to include a specific example of the problem rather than a vague description.

Comment: Probably, solutions exist only for some `C` and `D`.  For what ranges of these parameters do you expect solutions?

Answer (score 3):

I have edited my answer below extensively:

1. Simplified expansion about the point where `b` vanishes.
2. Improved accuracy of solution
3. Computed `eta` as a function of `d` for `c = 1`.

Integrating toward `b[eta] = y'[eta] = 0` is challenging, because `b[eta]` occurs in the denominator of the first ODE.  It is better to integrate toward `b'[0] = y[0] = 0`. Moreover, because the ODEs are autonomous, the origin of `t` can be shifted so that `eta` becomes `0` and `0` becomes `-eta`, which is convenient.  To avoid using reserved symbols and also for convenience, `D/(2 Sqrt[C])` is replaced by `d` and `C` by `c`.

```
ode = {b'[t]^2 == 1 - b[t]^2 + d b[t]^2 (y'[t]^2 - c (y[t]^2 - 1)^2), 
       y''[t] + 3 b'[t] y'[t]/b[t] == 2 c y[t] (y[t]^2 - 1)};
```

To integrate starting at `b[0] = y'[0] = 0`, where `ode[[1]]` is singular, the ODEs can be expanded about this point to obtain an approximate solution there:

```
CoefficientList[Normal@Series[#, {t, 0, 3}] /. {y'[0] -> 0, b[0] -> 0}, t] &
    /@ {Subtract @@ First[ode], implify[b[t] Subtract @@ Last[ode]]};
DeleteCases[Flatten[%], 0];
Solve[Thread[% == 0], Variables[%][[4 ;;]]];
{baprx, yaprx} = (Sum[Derivative[n][#][0] t^n/n!, {n, 0, 4}] /. 
    First[%] /. {y[0] -> y0, y'[0] -> 0, b[0] -> 0}) & /@ {b, y}

(* {-t + 1/6 t^3 (1 + c d - 2 c d y0^2 + c d y0^4), 
    y0 + 1/4 c t^2 y0 (-1 + y0^2) + 1/48 c t^4 y0 (-1 + y0^2) 
        (1 - c + c d + 3 c y0^2 - 2 c d y0^2 + c d y0^4)} *)
```

At the other boundary condition, where `b'[t] = 0`, `ode[[2]]` exhibits a branch point. Although the branch point is not an insurmountable problem, it is convenient to eliminate it by differentiating `ode[[2]]`.

```
Flatten@Solve[Last[ode], y''[t]] /. Equal -> Rule;
Simplify[(D[Subtract @@ First[ode], t] /. %)/(2 b'[t])] == 0;
ode1 = {%, Last[ode]}
(* {b[t] (1 + c d - 2 c d y[t]^2 + c d y[t]^4 + 2 d y'[t]^2) + b''[t] == 0, 
    y''[t] + 3 b'[t] y'[t]/b[t] == 2 c y[t] (y[t]^2 - 1)}; *)
```

The additional boundary condition, for `b'[0]`, introduced by this differentiation can be derived consistently from `baprx`.  Now, the following short code solves the ODEs for given `y0`.

```
eps = -10^-8;
ic = {b[t] == baprx, y[t] == yaprx, b'[t] == D[baprx, t], 
    y'[t] == D[yaprx, t]} /. t -> eps;
solp = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ode1, ic, 
    WhenEvent[b'[t] == 0, "StopIntegration"]}, {b'[t], y[t], b[t], 
    y'[t]}, {t, -5, eps}, {c, d, y0}];
```

From this, the boundary conditions at `b'[t] = 0` can be applied by (in the example `c = 1`, `d = -0.48`),

```
FindRoot[sf = solp[1, -.480, yf]; 
    Norm[sf[[1 ;; 2]] /. t -> (sf[[1]] /. t -> "Domain")[[1, 1]]], 
    {yf, .74, .78}, Evaluated -> False, MaxIterations -> 500]
s = solp[1, -.480, yf /. %];
tm = (s[[1]] /. t -> "Domain")[[1, 1]]
s /. t -> tm
Plot[s, {t, tm, eps}, LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[{b'[t], y[t], b[t], y'[t]}, {.1, .22}]]

(* {yf -> 0.59085} *)
(* -2.28386 *)
(* {1.9082*10^-17, -1.02002*10^-15, 1.25426, 0.490884} *)
```

[image]

From this solution, nearby solutions (in `d`) can be obtained using nearby starting guesses for `y0`.  It turns out, however, that solutions exist only for a small range of `d` values, at least for `c = 1`.  Some experimentation was needed to obtain the limits on `d`, which are approximately `d = -.47459185` with `y0 = 0.764158`.

[image]

and `d = -.49992 with` y0 = 0.0334762`.

[image]

Plots of `eta`, the negative of `tm`, and of `y0` as a function of `d` summarize the results of several such calculations.

[image]

[image]

*Second Set of Solutions*

A second set of solutions can be obtained by replacing `First[%]` by `Last[%]` in the expression for `{baprx, yaprx}`; i.e.,

```
{baprx, yaprx} = (Sum[Derivative[n][#][0] t^n/n!, {n, 0, 4}] /. 
    Last[%] /. {y[0] -> y0, y'[0] -> 0, b[0] -> 0}) & /@ {b, y}

(* {t + 1/6 t^3 (-1 - c d + 2 c d y0^2 - c d y0^4), 
    y0 + 1/4 c t^2 y0 (-1 + y0^2) + 1/48 c t^4 y0 (-1 + y0^2) 
        (1 - c + c d + 3 c y0^2 - 2 c d y0^2 + c d y0^4)} *)
```

With this change, the expressions for `solp`, etc. remains unchanged but produce different solutions, as shown below.  However, for convenience, define

```
fr[c_, d_, yg_] := Module[{yr}, 
    yr = FindRoot[sf = solp[c, d, yf]; Norm[sf[[1 ;; 2]] /. 
        t -> (sf[[1]] /. t -> "Domain")[[1, 1]]], 
        {yf, yg - .02, yg + .02}, Evaluated -> False];
    s = solp[c, d, yf /. yr];
    tm = (s[[1]] /. t -> "Domain")[[1, 1]];
{d, yf /. yr, tm, Norm[s[[;; 2]] /. t -> tm]}]
```

A sample solution for `c = 3` and positive `d` is

```
fr[3, .13, .3]
Plot[s, {t, tm, eps}, LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[{b'[t], y[t], b[t], y'[t]}, {.1, .22}]]

(* {0.12, 0.404346, -1.34058, 4.81741*10^-16} *)
```

[image]

The limits on `d` in this case are approximately `d = -0.122` with `y0 = 0.964856` and `d = 0.166` with `y0 = 0.0464389`.  Corresponding plots are

[image]

[image]

Finally, lots of eta, the negative of `tm`, and of `y0` as a function of `d` summarize the results of several such calculations.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this code! It seems to work pretty well but as you say it can be better optimized. If I figure something better I will post. I do think there is a missing factor of y0 in the expression for y'[eps]. Also, when I run the code the variable tm does not acquire a value and quite frankly I don't know how to extract it. Could you please clarify that? Finally, I am pretty sure that this can be expanded with ParametricNDSolve somehow.

Comment: @GeorgeFanaras There was a missing factor of `y0` in the expression for `y'[eps]`.  I have corrected this and made the necessary minor changes in the sample result.  Also, it is straightforward to use `ParametricNDSolve`, and doing so would make good sense in a more automated version of my answer.  I may try to produce an automated version, when I find time.

Comment: Actually the algorithm you wrote is incomplete since you are fixing the value y0. However, this value does not necessarily satisfy the boundary conditions. The correct approach would be write WhenEvent[Abs[Re[b'[t]]] < eps && Abs[Re[y[t]]]<eps , tm = t; "StopIntegration"] and use a shooting method that finds the value of y0 that satisfies it. I have not been able to figure out how to write this yet.

Comment: @GeorgeFanaras Actually what I did for the sample result in my answer was to choose `y0`, find the value of `tm` at which `y = 0`, and then adjust `d` to cause `b' = 0` there.  Not optimal, but I ran out of time to automate the process.

Comment: @GeorgeFanaras My update partially automates the solutions and obtains `eta` vs `d` for `c = 1`.  I hope that you find this approach helpful.

Comment: thank you!! You're the boss! I managed to plot everything I needed to. I am actually interested in the regime of D>0 and C>2. I had to make a small tweek on the WhenEvent command and insert the condition "y[t]==0". Otherwise I would obtain trivial solutions y=0. It also seems that it gets problematic if one includes both conditions in the WhenEvent command. I don't understand the reason why this happens, but it does not seem to be dangerous since the obtained solutions satisfy the boundary condition.

Comment: @GeorgeFanaras  Your last comment prompted me to examine the second set of solutions, which I shall add to the bottom of my answer above soon.  Probably, you will find these solutions of greater value.  Note that I still do not include `y[t]==0` in `WhenEvent`, for the reason you gave.

Comment: thank you. There is no need for me I basically got what I needed. I wanted to replicate the results of https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.46.2345 in section IV and your code works perfectly